# Problem in positioning the location points in google map using R

Tags: r, ggmap

I am facing problem in creating map. I have downloaded a shape file from-

location link:  "https://data.humdata.org/dataset/80920682-bbb5-421e-b7ac-f89b7b640a5c/resource/c545d196-bc2c-44ed-9028-316ab080a41c"

zip file link: https://data.humdata.org/dataset/80920682-bbb5-421e-b7ac-f89b7b640a5c/resource/c545d196-bc2c-44ed-9028-316ab080a41c/download/bgd_poi_healthfacilities_lged.zip

After extracting the data I have found a shape file. I am trying to plot this shape file in google map using R code. But It is not showing anything?

```
library(maptools)
library(ggmap)

counties.mpl <- readShapePoints("bgd_poi_healthfacilities_lged")

#Coordinates looks like:

counties.mpl@coords

       coords.x1 coords.x2
    0  531533.8   2524464
    1  531004.7   2531410
    2  533228.5   2525061
    3  531723.1   2488972
    4  532347.8   2492098
    5  518104.8   2520361

#map code:
mymap <- get_map(location="Bangladesh", zoom=6)
ggmap(mymap)+
  geom_point(data=counties.mpl@coords, 
             aes(x=counties.mpl@coords[,1], y=counties.mpl@coords[,2]))
```

Could anybody please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those values do not look like latitudes ad longitudes.

Comment: I think so. May be they are UTM.

Comment: They are, but we need to know in which system.

Comment: prj file says GCS_WGS_1984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have noted, your shapefile uses a different coordinate system, & you'll need to transform it to lat / lon before the `geom_point()` layer can sit nicely over `mymap`.

Your shapefile's .prj file begins with:

```
PROJCS["BangladeshTM WGS1984",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984", ...
```

The link [here](https://vsp.pnnl.gov/help/vsample/ESRI_PRJ_File.htm) explains what each part means, but for our purpose, you just need to know that the shapefile's projected coordinate system is "BangladeshTM WGS1984", i.e. Bangladesh Transverse Mercator, coded as [EPSG:3106](https://epsg.io/3106).

The typical lat / lon coordinate system that `ggmap()` expects is WGS 84, coded as [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326).

**TLDR: Convert your data's projection from EPSG:3106 to EPSG:4326, and plot accordingly.**

```
counties.mpl <- readShapePoints("bgd_poi_healthfacilities_lged")

# define current projection
proj4string(counties.mpl) <- CRS("+init=epsg:3106") # Bangladesh Transverse Mercator system

# remap to lat / long projection
counties.mpl.remapped <- spTransform(counties.mpl, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

# extract the coordinates as a data frame.
df <- as.data.frame(counties.mpl.remapped@coords)
colnames(df) <- c("lon", "lat")

# plot results
mymap <- get_map(location="Bangladesh", zoom=6)

ggmap(mymap) +
  geom_point(data = df)
```

[image: plot]